# Enable IPV6_RECVPKTINFO on MacOs

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to build a UDP server, I want to access to the socket option  `IPV6_RECVPKTINFO`.

When I try to access this option, the following message appears : "error: use of undeclared identifier 'IPV6_RECVPKTINFO".

The libraries `<sys/socket.h>` and `<netinet/in.h>` are include.

I am working on MacOS, is there a way to enable this option or is there an alternative ?

Comment: @SeanBright that really is the answer you should post it and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `__APPLE_USE_RFC_3542` to use the newer constants. Put this before your other includes:

```
#define __APPLE_USE_RFC_3542
```

Or do it on the command line:

```
… -D__APPLE_USE_RFC_3542 …
```

Comment: hi Sean, can you please give more info where I need to add this , I am facing same issue (in iOS) with this constant but those are mainly used by third party spm package , how I can I resolve for them